# How to get only specific values from all mongodb documents and return them as json?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

I have user documents like this for each individual user :

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "638df6dd4774e9573010b138"
  },
  "username": "abc",
  "email": "abc@xyz.com",
  "stats": {
    "ranking": "1",
    "match": "0.214"
  },
  "stats_extra": {
    "pre_ranking": "10",
    "pre_match": "0.290"
  }
}
```

and I am trying to fetch only "username" and "stats" for each individual user and return them as JSON api response.

**I can print usernames and stats for each individual user like this :**

```
@app.get("/Stats",  tags=["userstats"])
def get_stats():
    for doc in app.Users.find():
        print(doc["username"],doc["stats"])
    return { }
```

**but I am struggling to find the right way to send all user's usernames and stats as json response like this: **

```
{"data": [ 
{"username":"abc", "stats":{"ranking": "1","match": "0.214"}} ,
{"username":"xyz", "stats":{"ranking": "10","match": "0.2104"}} ,
{"username":"ijk", "stats":{"ranking": "12","match": "0.2014"}}]
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the projection parameter to indicate which fields of the documents have to be returned. Check out [this link](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-specific-fields-in-embedded-documents).

In your case something like this should work:

```py
app.Users.find(projection={"username": 1, "stats": 1})
```

Comment: you used "1" as the value of username and stats , what does this do ? when I used what you suggested , it returns empty array

Comment: My bad, the [projection parameter is in the second place](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/), I've edited the comment to solve this. A 1 indicates that the field has to be returned, if you use `{"username": 0, "stats": 0}` you get a dictionary with all the fields except username and stats.

Comment: even the updated answer return only the Cursor and not the values or json....
does this solution need to be included inside of the for loop ? I have tried it with and without the loop and its only returning `<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x000002BBAB206ED0>`

Comment: `find` method returns a cursor by default. You've got to use it inside your loop, or do something like `list(app.Users.find(projection={"username": 1, "stats": 1}))`.